# Google Feed not scheduling - Failed to obtain the file information

Tags: xml

So I have been running my website for about 3 months now, the datafeed was working fine for 2months... with the scheduled uploader.

but now I have to do it manually..

I'm getting this "Failed to obtain the file information" from google.

ive used this feed url: http://www.mysite.co.uk/googlebase.xml

and this feed url: http://www.mysite.co.uk/index.php?route=feed/google_base

any ideas, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was using opencart and forcing ssl on all pages, however it is best not to index your site with https.

so i removed https from every page but the checkout and account pages.